# What is a junior researcher in academia

Tags: academic-life, assistant-professor

Can we call someone a junior researcher if he or she has obtained their Ph.D recently and also has research stay abroad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would classify a "junior" researcher as pretty much anyone who does not yet have a permanent position. (The question of whether a tenure-track faculty member is a "junior" researcher might be open, but anything "below" that is not, at least in my mind.)

So yes, someone who has had a research stay abroad and has recently received a PhD is still very much a "junior" researcher.